# Android Fragment Transition

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am trying to load a fragment which by fragment transation which has slide animation. The sliding effect starts with a delay of about 2-3 seconds after i press the button. I have reduced the heaviness of my UI as much as possible. Also, there are no background processes running? ow to start the sliding effect as soon as I press the button

Answer (score 0):

Try prefetching data so that you don't have to do much processing when starting the fragment. If loading certain information takes some time, do it in the background and display default information like "Retrieving data..."

If you'd like to have a more detailed answer, please post code so we can help.